# How do I visualize an equation written in matlab code in LaTeX form?

Tags: matlab

Lets say I'm using MATLAB and i've written this equation

```
%function value
y=I-p1*(alpha2/alpha1*p1/p2)^(-1/gamma1)*gamma2/gamma1*x^(gamma2/gamma1-1)-p2;
```

Is there any easy way I can have it visualized like this:

[image]

Im sure anyone who uses matlab would find this feature useful in checking if youve entered everything right. Thanks and if you feel this belongs in stackoverflow, please leave a comment ill delete the question and repost it over there.

Comment: Have a look at m-code to latex converter: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24515-m-code-to-latex-converter

Comment: Hopefully that's not the output that comes from that MATLAB function, because they certainly don't match... Where does `I` come from? Why does it equal `0` instead of `y` all of a sudden? Why isn't `p2` multiplied by `x2`?

Comment: If you have the symbolic toolbox, the `latex` command should be able to do that

Comment: @garciaj You need a LaTeX interpreter. Or paste it here: www.texify.com/

Comment: As written this looks like a recommendation questions (and therefore off-topic), but it is clear from the comments that it should be possible to rescue it.

Comment: @dmckee may i ask what the point of your comment is

Comment: It is a suggestion that you *fix* it. Lest it get put on hold.

Comment: @dmckee ahh now i understand you, ive edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, the matlab expression does not match the typeset equation you showed.  This was probably just an example image.

As the comments also suggested, you'll likely want to use LaTeX.  In the symbolic toolbox, you may be able to compile it in it's current form.  Also in the software EES, the equation may be compiled in it's current form.  However, in general LaTeX, you'll have to add a few things.  Your equation is:

```
y=I-p1*(alpha2/alpha1*p1/p2)^(-1/gamma1)*gamma2/gamma1*x^(gamma2/gamma1-1)-p2;
```

In LaTeX, you'll want to add some syntax and wrap it in some math environment such as equation:

```
\begin{equation}
y = I - p_1 \left(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{\gamma_1}} \frac{\gamma_2}{\gamma_1} x^{\frac{\gamma_2}{\gamma_1}-1} - p_2
\end{equation}
```

Note, I didn't compile this, just handwriting it.  Should be close though.